# Scroll to center with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using this code to scroll to horizontal center of my website.

```
function scrollCenter() {
    scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
}
```

How could I get an animated scrolling effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property to animate is `scrollLeft`.

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate({
    scrollLeft: ($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2
}, 'slow' );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2SGBS/